# Lakatos on continuity and invariance to rotation

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, philosophy

On page 159, note 21, of *Cauchy and the continuum*, Imre Lakatos writes: "The modern definition of continuity [the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition] is strongly counter-intuitive, e.g. it is not invariant to rotation".

I have two questions:

1. Does Lakatos mean that there is a continuous function $f$ such that ROTATION$(f)$ is not continuous?
2. What are rotation and invariance to rotation in this context? (Lakatos does not explain the terms and a search on the internet did not clarify the issue.)

Thanks very much.

Comment: By the way, I object to the assertion that the modern definition of continuity is not intuitive. I strongly object to the assertion that it is counter-intuitive. And I vehemently obect to the assertion that it is strongly counter-intuitive.

Comment: @DanielFischer What about continuous but nowhere differentiable functions? What bearing, if any, do they have on your objecting or not to the assertion that the modern definition of continuity is not intuitive?

Comment: @QuinnCulver They have no bearing on it. It is of course not obvious that such things exist (until one has done enough topology ;), but non-obvious consequences are ubiquitous. The informal idea that "small changes in the argument cause only small changes in the result" is still, as far as I can see, best captured by our definition. The only somewhat plausible alternative I can see would be a "pointwise Lipschitz condition", and that's clearly too restrictive, $\sqrt[n]{x}$ should be continuous at $0$.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: what bearing, if any, do the following have on the issue of whether continuous nowhere differentiable functions are *counter*intuitive? (1) Distinguish two notions of curve: movement of a point (which, intuitively must have a derivative somewhere because the derivative is the velocity) vs boundary of two regions (for which I would say that intuition does not require somewhere differentiability). (2) Weierstrass function is the limit of a series of somewhere differentiable functions and it is not clear that our intuition says something about limits of every infinite process.

Comment: It seems, @DanielFischer and MatteeoBianchetti, that what I think and what Daniel thinks about the modern notion being intuitive or not are not relevant here. What is relevant is what Lakatos thinks. What was continuity originally trying to capture? Was it "small changes in the argument cause only small changes in the result"? Or something else? (Sorry thoughts here are muddled.)

Comment: @QuinnCulver: you ask a good question but I do not know the answer (and I do not know whether there was a unique thing that continuity *originally* tried to capture). Moreover, adding to my comment above, it appears that there are continuous curves defined by motion that have no tangents. See Neikirk, *A class of continuous curves defined by motion which have no tangent lines*, 1930. (I have not been able to locate the paper though: if anyone can point to where I can find it, that would be great).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the author did not further specify the meaning, then, in general,
there is no way to determine the meaning intended. However, it is
possible to make educated guesses. Given a function $\,f(x)\,$ on an
interval, then the set of points $\,(x,f(x))\,$ forms a parametrized curve. This curve
can be rotated. What the author probably meant is that there are some
examples where the original curve is continuous, and a rotated version
also comes from a function, but the rotated version is not continuous
at some points. This all has to be made explicit, of course,
but that is my guess.

Comment: But when the rotated version, parametrise it as $(\xi(x), \eta(x))$ first, is the graph of a function, then $\xi$ is a continuous bijection between two intervals, hence a homeomorphism, and $g(t) = \eta(\xi^{-1}(t))$ is also continuous. Thus in this sense continuity _is_ rotation-invariant. Of course if we drop the assumption that $f$ be defined on an interval we can give examples where a rotated version becomes the graph of a discontinuous function, but expecting that kind of rotation-invariance would be silly. So I'm at a loss what Lakatos may have meant.

Comment: Thanks to both. @DanielFischer could you elaborate on the continuous function undefined on some points on an interval (if I understand) whose rotated version is discontinuous?

Comment: @orient Define $f \colon [0,1] \cup (2,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, $f(x) = 1$ for $2 < x \leqslant 3$. Rotate counterclockwise around $(0,0)$ by an angle of $\pi/4$ and you have the graph of a function with a jump discontinuity.